# Remove extended selector in SASS

Tags: sass

How to remove a particular selector.

**Required SASS**

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            .d {
                .g {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }

        .c > {
            .e {
                .h {
                    ...
                }
            }
            .f {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Generated**

```
.a .b .c .d .g { ... }
.a .b .c > .e .h { ... }
.a .b .c > .f { ... }
```

**Combined SASS**

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c > {
            .d { // remove > for .d
                .g {
                    ...
                }
            }
            .e {
                .h {
                    ...
                }
            }
            .f {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Generated**

```
.a .b .c > .d .g { ... } // extra  > 
.a .b .c > .e .h { ... }
.a .b .c > .f { ... }
```

How to remove `>` selector for `.d` and it's siblings in the above SASS, so that it is efficient, rather than re-writing the same selector multiple times?

Comment: Just as an aside - your CSS rules are way to specific, which will probably cause issues further down the line. Any more than 2 or 3 levels of specificity and there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @rwacarter Yup, but it's the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can achieve this using [@at-root](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root):

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c > {
            @at-root .a .b .c {
                .d {
                    .g {
                        color: red;
                    }
                }
            }
            .e {
                .h {
                    color: red;
                }
            }
            .f {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will generate:

```
.a .b .c .d .g {
  color: red;
}
.a .b .c > .e .h {
  color: red;
}
.a .b .c > .f {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, is there any other way to remove repeated `.a .b .c` after `@at-root`.? How about using ` @at-root (without: ....) `

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating selectors is not elegant in Sass.

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c > {
            @at-root #{set-nth(nth(&, 1), length(nth(&, 1)), '')} {
              .d {
                  .g {
                      color: red;
                  }
              }
            }
            .e {
                .h {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
            .f {
                color: green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.a .b .c .d .g {
  color: red;
}
.a .b .c > .e .h {
  color: blue;
}
.a .b .c > .f {
  color: green;
}
```

It is by far cleaner to just nest properly in the first place:

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            .d {
                .g {
                    color: red;
                }
            }
            > .e {
                .h {
                    color: blue;
                }
            }
            > .f {
                color: green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems much complex than existing, & the nesting `.c` used more than once, I wanted to avoid that.