# Sass only selecting parent

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to target only the parent selector of a nested selector? For example:

```
#rootSelector{
    .parentSelect{
        padding: 15px 0;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        form &&onlyParentSelector&&:first-child {
            padding-top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Should output:

```
form .parentSelect:first-child {}
```

Rather than of course when using `&`

```
form #rootSelector .parentSelect:first-child {}
```

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064137/remove-extended-selector-in-sass

Comment: Thanks for the heads ups guys. Exactly what I'm after